# Jacoco coverage percentage maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jacoco

When runnning mvn test, my spring boot application builds succesfully. When I do mvn clean install or mvn clean verify, build fails. This is because I have minimum code coverage ratio configured to 80%. When I run mvn clean install/verify, the result shows **instructions covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.50.**

Before setting the minimum threshold, running mvn clean install, gave the below result, which says 65% covered. What is missing in my configuration? Am I missing anything? How can I get jacoco pick the correct code covered?

[image]

Here is my pom

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.bitmc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>8.35.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
            <exclude>*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-instrument</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>PACKAGE</element>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com.pip</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.50</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am using java version "1.8.0_202"

Answer (score 0):

In you's plugin config need set like that;

`

```
        ...
         <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/PACKEGE YOU WANT EXCLUDE.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>65%</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

in your's exemple the tag pluguin is out from plugins tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jacoco with PowerMockito, and the class which you want to cover is taken in PrepareForTest, then in that case it will show you 0% coverage.
Try removing the target class from PrepareForTest